# Snowflake CEIL Function - round up to next 0.1 kilometer

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column containing measurement values in meters.
I want to round them up (ceil) them to the next 100m and return it as a km value.

Special thing is: if the original value is a "round" number (100m increment) it should be ceiled up to the next 100m increment (see line 3 in the example below).

Example:

```
meter_value     kilometer_value
1111            1.2
 111            0.2
1000            1.1
```

I think I can get the first two lines by doing:

```
ceil(meter_value/1000,1) as kilometer_value
```

The solution I thought of to fix the edge case in line three is to just add 1 meter always:

```
ceil((meter_value+1)/1000,1) as kilometer_value
```

It seems a bit clumsy, is there a better way/alternative function to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg's answer is good, simpler to read to me would be to

- divide by 100
- floor
- add 1
- ceil
- divide by 10

```
select
    column1 as meter_value
    ,ceil(((meter_value + iff(meter_value % 100 = 0, 1, 0))/1000), 1) as greg
    ,ceil(floor(meter_value/100)+1)/10 as simeon
from values
    (1111)
    ,(111)
    ,(1000)
    ,(1)
    ,(0)
;
```

| METER_VALUE | GREG | SIMEON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,111 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 111 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 1,000 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 0 | 0.1 | 0.1 |

do we want to mention negative values? I mean it distance, so it's a directionless magnitude, right?

anyway with negative value, both our methods the +1 forces the boundary case to be wrong.

### Actually:

Once you have floored adding the 1 or 0.1 if you divide by 1000 vs 100 first, you don't need to ceil at all

thus two short forms can be:

```
    ,ceil(floor(meter_value/100)+1)/10 as version_a
    ,(floor(meter_value/100)+1)/10     as version_b
    ,floor(meter_value/1000,1)+0.1     as version_c
```

Comment: SQL golf for the fun, and readability. what joy!

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if it's divisible by 100 and only add one if it is:

```
ceil(((meter_value + iff(meter_value % 100 = 0, 1, 0))/1000), 1)
```

This will prevent situations where (if decimal parts are allowed) adding 1 to a value of 999.5 would not be accurate if adding one all the time.